# CSS inline-block grid

Tags: css

I've just started to learn html and css. I'm trying to create a 3x3 grid with inline-block "method". This is the code so far:

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="ex.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <title>ex</title>
    </head>

    <body>
            <div id="r1"></div>
            <div id="r2"></div>
            <div id="r3"></div>
            <div id="r4"></div>
            <div id="r5"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#r1 {
background-color: blue;
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
display: inline-block;
}
#r2 {
background-color: red;
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
display: inline-block;
}
#r3 {
background-color: blue;
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
display: inline-block;
}
#r4 {
background-color: green;
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
}
#r5 {
background-color: yellow;
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
}
```

Can someone help me to position #r5 (yellow box) near #r4 (green box) horizontally?

Comment: Did you forgot inline-block in the last couple of them?

Comment: After the third block on the first row I want to start another one and if I insert inline-block in the last ones then they all go on the first row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be sexy, but for basic purposes you could just add a line break every three divs:

```
<div id="r3"></div>
<br>
<div id="r4"></div>
```

Another alternative (perhaps more appropriate) is to set a fixed width for the container too, in your example:

```
body { width: 1000px; }
```

will actually take care of breaking the boxes apart, so every one of them could be inline-block.

And by the way, you don't need to keep duplicating all rules, try this:

```
div { display: inline-block; height: 300px; width: 300px; }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the only method I've found to do this. It is quite a shame. Pseudo elements do not seem to do the trick either.

Comment: @Jason if you're curious, see my answer for a CSS3 way to do it.

Comment: @AlexPodworny Yup, Flex-box can do it. Unfortunately, I always must support IE9 and often IE8, so it doesn't work in that circumstance.

Answer (score 2):

```
You need to wrap every row with another div like that:

HTML:


<body>
    <div class="row">
            <div id="r1"></div>
            <div id="r2"></div>
            <div id="r3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
            <div id="r4"></div>
            <div id="r5"></div>
    </div>
</body> 


CSS:
    #r1 {
        background-color: blue;

    }
    #r2 {
        background-color: red;
    }
    #r3 {
        background-color: blue;  
    }
    #r4 {
        background-color: green;

    }
    #r5 {
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    .row > div{
        display: inline-block;
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Flex is here to save the day! This is exactly the type of thing flex was made for, but beware - support for it on old browsers isn't very good. If you don't care too much about old browsers then I suggest using flex, as formatting how the page looks via HTML is frowned upon.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F62XA/).

HTML:

```
<div id="container">            
    <div class="box" id="r1"></div>
    <div class="box" id="r2"></div>
    <div class="box" id="r3"></div>
    <div class="box" id="r4"></div>
    <div class="box" id="r5"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#r1 {
background-color: blue;
}
#r2 {
background-color: red;
}
#r3 {
background-color: blue;
}
#r4 {
background-color: green;
}
#r5 {
background-color: yellow;
}

.box
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 100px;
    flex: 0 0 100px;
}

#container
{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;

    width: 300px;
}
```